# Does it make sense to proxy multiple tornado-based processes with nginx, where both of them are non-blocking I/O based?

Tags: nginx, proxy, tornado, nonblocking, httpserver

I found several online articles which explains how to proxy multiple tornado processes (using supervisord or something) with nginx, but can't understand the reason why they're using tornado as a back-end server framework.

According to my understanding, both tornado and nginx are non-blocking I/O based, so if you want the benefits of non-blocking I/O, isn't one of them enough? Are there reasons to choose non-blocking I/O based server for both front-end and back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to run multiple tornado processes and proxy to all of them. The reason is the GIL: each python process can only make use of one core, so to make use of all the cores on a machine you must run multiple processes.

There are a number of ways to run and manage multiple Tornado processes, and not all of them require a load balancer like nginx, but this is the recommended configuration because it allows for each process to be restarted independently for zero-downtime updates.

The benefits of non-blocking I/O apply at every level. Using nginx as a load balancer does slightly reduce the benefit you would see by using Tornado on the backend, but the benefits are still there, especially for sites using long polling or websockets.